# Why does Azure issue a security threat if my query fails from the vscode mssql ext?

Tags: azure-security

If I execute a query from vscode that fails, why should Azure issue a security threat for this? How should I prevent this from happening (other than never submitting a query that fails, lol)? Is this a permissions issue? Can I have the admin suppress this type of 'threat' from my machine/login? This also happens if there is a failed query from python/sqlalchemy. This doesn't happen often but it is rather annoying to have to explain.

Threat: Potential SQL Injection

Edit:
[Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnEJ1.png)

[Threat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv5j1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug. I've reported this to someone on the product team to check. Can you send an example of this with a screenshot to me at AzCommunity@microsoft.com so that I can bubble this up?

Comment: Hi Marilee, thanks for this insight I really appreciate it. I sorta get why this threat assessment would get triggered but it seems a bit excessive given the situation. What is the best way to avoid triggering this?

Comment: I have asked and hopefully will get feedback from the PG soon.